# Proof verification: interior of a nowhere dense set is empty

Tags: general-topology

A set $S$ in a topological space $X$ is called nowhere dense if its exterior is dense in $X$.

Now suppose that $A$ is a nowhere dense set. We have $Int(A)= X-Cl(A^c)=X-X=\emptyset$. Is it correct?

Comment: What is meant by "exterior"of $X$? Is it the complement of the interior of $X$, or is the complement of $X$ itself?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг exterior of $A$ is defined to be the interior of $A^c$

Comment: Then the proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

You can also prove it saying that since $\mathring A$ is an open set, $\mathring{A}^\complement$ is closed and, since it contains $A^\complement$, $\mathring{A}^\complement\supset\overline{A^\complement}=X$. Therefore, $\mathring{A}^\complement=X$ and therefore $\mathring A=\emptyset$. But it is basically the same idea.

Comment: I just wanted to know if my proof was the most natural proof. I have another proof which is easier but not the first proof which would come to mind: Since $A$ is nowhere dense, if $Int(A)$ was not empty, there would exist a nonempty open set $V$ contained in $Int(A)\cap A^c=\emptyset$, a contradiction

Comment: @Selflearner It is quite natural, yes. Whether it is the *most* natural is a matter of taste.